# Create a keyboard shortcut in excel to insert specific symbol - Mac Excel 2011

Tags: excel, excel-2011

Trying to figure out how to create a keyboard shortcut to insert the delta symbol (δ).

Cannot find any documentation to create a shortcut for a symbol based on a google search.

Comment: There are step by step instructions for this here: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/assign-a-keystroke-shortcut-to-insert-a-symbol-or-special-character/  I can't say if they will work on the Mac in precisely the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the most viable way to do that is creating a VBA macro that inserts the character and assigning it a shortcut.

I'm on Excel 2019 and need to redefine my keyboard shortcut for the basic Excel functions (such as Find, Replace, etc.): looks like the shortcut customization has disappeared in the most recent Office versions...